# Practice exercises functional analysis

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request

I am following a course functional analysis and i am using the book linear functional analysis of Bryan Rynne and Martin Youngson.

I have noticed that the questions are relatively easy and i need to practice more, so does anyone know a source of practice-exercises which are related to inner products/norms/linear operators/banach/hilbert spaces etc....?

Kees

Answer (score 1):

Exercises in functional analysis   by Costara, Constantin Popa, Dumitru

https://books.google.co.in/books/about/Exercises_in_Functional_Analysis.html?id=iZ1962_xt7sC